# How to encode input() variable to bytes without adding backslashes

Tags: python, unicode, byte, encode, python-3.3

I need to create a bytes variable from `input()` and use it for `socket.sendall([bytes])`
but when I do `input_var.encode("utf-8")` it adds another backslash after a backslash:

1. This is my input variable:

   ```
   "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
   ```
2. This is what I want in a byte variable:

   ```
   "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
   ```
3. But when I do `encode("utf-8")` this is what I get:

   ```
   "GET / HTTP/1.1\\r\\n\\r\\n"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
3>> codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')('foo\\nbar')[0]
'foo\nbar'
```